# Owner of lock unknown in IBM JVM version 7

Tags: java, jvm, locking, ibm-jdk

I have a situation where lots of threads are blocked on some ReentrantReadWriteLock but for some reason the owner is not known.

```
3XMTHREADBLOCK     Parked on:
java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync@0xC3C0E5E8 Owned by: <unknown>
```

Is this because the owner thread has existed?
Why doesn't the JVM release the lock?
Can there be other reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread is parked and not blocked. Threads enter the parked state through the `java.util.concurrent` API.
Parked threads are listed as parked on the blocker object that was passed to the underlying `java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park()` method, if such an object was supplied. If a blocker object was not supplied, threads are listed as `Parked on: <unknown>`.
If the object that was passed to the `park()` method extends the `java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractOwnableSynchronizer` class, and uses the methods of that class to keep track of the owning thread, then information about the owning thread is shown. If the object does not use the `AbstractOwnableSynchronizer` class, the owning thread is listed as `<unknown>`.
For more detailed information take a look at [Blocked thread information](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.win.70.doc/diag/tools/javadump_tags_blocked_threads.html) in the IBM knowledge center (which is the source for this answer).